# How can I successfully do TDD on Xcode with C++ ?

Tags: c++, xcode, unit-testing, tdd

Currently I'm working on OpenGL ES 1.0 releated project using C++ on iOS.

I just cannot find a way smoothly integrating any unit-testing framework to do TDD on this particular setting.

Working environment:

1. OS : OS/X 10.7
2. Target device : iOS
3. main language : C++
4. IDE : Xcode
5. OpenGL ES 1.0

I tried googletest, but in order to make googletest work, I should able to create command line application, 
but since I'm using OpenGL ES 1.0, I cannot really import them to command line application on Mac.

I tried new method called catch, but I don't know how I can integrate with Xcode.

Anyone has good solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do TDD programming. First of all I establish the new functionality I need to add and then I establish all the external dependencies this functionality will have. For example, I have a dependency in my current project to a c api which provides information about the model I'm using. I'm also dependant on the command line as the client can enter commands to which I must respond. This command line is via a special terminal, the details of which I'm not interested in.

So I create interface classes for these external dependencies and then I use only these interfaces in my code. As a result I don't need the model's c++ library or the terminal's c++ library when doing my testing (more on this later). Here's an example of an interface for writing to the command line:

```
class ICommandLineOutput
{
public:
  virtual void WriteLine(std::string&) = 0;
};
```

So lets say I'm asked to write a class which writes the time to the command line, called WriteTime. Then, what I will do is pass an object of type **ICommandLineOutput** to this classes constructor and work only with this interface. I don't care about what kind of command line I'm working with, just its interface. I can then use whatever command line class I want as long as it has the ICommandLineOutput class as its base.

```
class WriteTime
{
public:
  explicit WriteTime(ICommandLineOutput commandLine): _commandLine(commandLine){}
  ...
};
```

So when unit testing, I will have a separate C++ Project in which I will test each class that I write. This project can use Google Test and it can be a command line project. So even if you're writing a GUI application which is contained within a GUI C++ Project, the tests have there own project.

Lets say I wish to test my class which writes the time to the command line. I will do this in a class called TestWriteTime. I will use GoogleMock to create a mock of the ICommandLineOutput interface. The mock can then be questioned and/or configured on a test by test bases in order to establish if WriteTime is behaving as expected. For example, I can check the number of times WriteLine() is called and what parameters it receives.

Finally, in my current project I'm working with a linux based project with a huge amount of dependencies. The application also takes a long time to start. However, I have a windows console project in which I do my testing. This application executes in less that a second which is ideal for TDD.